# Running FirefoxDriver headless in Mac OSX Mountain Lion 10.8

Tags: macos, firefox, selenium, xvfb

I want to run my webdriver test headless. On ubuntu machine, I could do this by launching Xvfb and configure my FirefoxDriver's DISPLAY option. On mac, it doesn't work since application on mac uses Quarts, not X.

Googling a while, I found there *has been* firefox-x11 on mac ports, which doesn't exist at a moment either on ports(http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=firefox) or fink. One option might be using headless WebDriver class such as PhantomJSDriver, but is there any solution for using FirefoxDriver headless on Mac OS?

Comment: It's too bad FF x11 for Mac, is no longer available. See these references for some insight: https://sourceforge.net/p/fink/mailman/message/34047822/, https://trac.macports.org/ticket/42087